ffmpeg - concatenating identical audio-only files results in "non-montonic DTS" warning
I am trying to join some video files and have an issue. I have boiled down the problem to the following minimal working example. I create a 2-second mp4 with a silent audio stream:
$ ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc -c:a aac -t 2 a.mp4

I then create a file containing the file names to be concatenated:
$ cat videos.txt               
file a.mp4
file a.mp4

Then I concatenate the videos:
$ ffmpeg -f concat -i videos.txt -c copy combine.mp4

which gives me this warning:
[mp4 @ 0x638776cb5a80] Non-monotonic DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 89088, current: 88200; changing to 89089. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.

How do I properly generate the audio file so that I don't get these warnings?

Change the container to matroska first, setting the TS to zero.
for file in *.mp4; do filename="${file%.*}"; ffmpeg -i "$filename".mp4 -c copy -avoid_negative_ts make_zero "$filename".mkv; done

Then do the concatenation.You won't have a single error after they are .mkv.

There is no visible error but still tracks may be desynced.

@akostadinov You must first make all of the files .mkv before concat.  It will correct the TS, setting it to zero. Then you concatenate the .mkv files.  If there are offsets, it will correct them, but a lot of the time you won't even have that warning.  I have not experienced any loss of sync.  That's why generating the .mkv instead of .mp4 works for Trevor.  Matroska can handle the audio, where mpeg-4 cannot.

I'm not actually concatenating. I'm converting a file created by this stupid intel arc control app. And there is desync watching the original file as well. So I assume another fix is needed here. Although I couldn't make ffmpeg's atempo and rubberband filters do the right thing.

@akostadinov If it slowly goes out of sync, that's a hard one to correct because it's not just an offset, it's a continual skew.  There's no place to adjust the audio that it won't just skew out of sync, over and over.

The two filters I listed above are supposed to be able to extend or shorten the audio as specified. There are other questions about using them to correct audio length. Logic is that we know that both streams should be of the same length. So if we stretch or shorten the audio track to match the video track, that should do the trick. As I said, I couldn't make these two plugins to work. But in general tracks can be extracted and stretched by other means.

I just figured out that I can avoid this warning by simply generating the first file as an mkv rather than an mp4:
$ ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc -c:a aac -t 2 a.mkv


There is no visible error but still tracks may be desynced.
